# On Luke 10:16 Invoked by a Pope or an Ecumenical Council

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-luke, papacy, ecumenical-council, pius-xii

> He that heareth you, heareth me; and he that despiseth you, despiseth me; and he that despiseth me, despiseth him that sent me.
> — Luke 10:16 (D-R)

I am aware of these three instances:

**Vatican II, *Lumen Gentium*** P20: "This sacred Council teaches that the Bishops, from divine institution, have taken the place of the Apostles, as the pastors of the Church: he who hears them, hears Christ; he who spurns them, spurns Christ, and Him who sent Christ."

**Pope Pius XII, *Humani Generis***: "Nor should we think that the things taught in Encyclical letters do not of themselves call for assent, on the plea that in them the Pontiffs do not exercise the Supreme power of their Magisterium. For these things are taught with the ordinary Magisterium, of which it is also correct to say: 'He who hears you, hears me.'"

**Fourth Council of Constantinople (870)** (DS 661): "Since we believe that the word of the Lord, which Christ said to the holy Apostles and his disciples, *He who receives you, receives me* and *he who spurns you, spurns me* was said to all those too who after them became Supreme Pontiffs and shepherds in the Catholic Church ..."

Can anyone cite other instances of either a papal document or an Ecumenical Council of the Catholic Church where an interpretation of Luke 10:16 is given?